# MS Access NOT In List Event Work-around?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with an unbound combo "search" and a command button "close form". When someone types a value into the search combo, and the value is not found in the search, it triggers the not in list event, so far so good.

My challenge is this: if the person types the value into the search combo, sees that no records are returned (in the dropdown of the combo), then goes to click the command button "close form", the not in list event still fires with the error message even though they have already clicked the "close" button.

When stepping through the code you see that even after the click of the command button the active control is still the combo box because it's trying to finish the not in list event.

Access doesn't even know the command button was clicked, all it knows is that the combo lost focus... so in order to close the form, they have to click the command button twice.

Here is my existing code-

```
Private Sub cboItemSearch_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
    Me.cboItemSearch = ""
    Response = acDataErrContinue

End Sub
```

Does anyone have a work-around for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code, but I'm thinking you're missing something like `Response = acDataErrContinue`  [ComboBox.NotInList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/combobox-notinlist-event-access)

Comment: Hi- thanks for helping, nope, got that... I added code above.

Comment: You'll notice that the command button never receives the click event - the focus never leaves the combo box as the cursor will remain in the combo box after it is cleared - it's not actually clicking the exit button twice.

Comment: That's correct, the focus never leaves the combo. Is there a work around for this? As in, when the close form button is clicked, the not in list event fires, and then the form closes? Thanks! This is a mystery! I am sure I am not the only one who would like a way to solve this behavior :)

Comment: Can you change the Limit to List property to No or will that mess up something else?  If you can, the NotInList event won't fire and won't intercept the click event of another control.

Comment: Don't use NotInList event, let Access nag users they entered a value that is not in list. They'll eventually learn to pay attention.